# android custom togglebutton border

Tags: android, border, togglebutton

I have a grid of 64 togglebuttons in an 8x8 form. when the app runs, it sets each togglebutton's background/drawable to a colour. this is done in the program, not the xml. my problem is that while there seems to be space between the buttons on the graphical layout of the app, when the app runs, and changes the buttons to a colour, the space disappears. this makes the buttons look like a single plate, with no definition between buttons.

What I want is to put a border on the buttons to make it clear where each button is.

the function of the buttons is to be used to indicate a musical note being pressed. when the button is pressed, the colour of the button turns from grey to light blue, and adds the note to a sequence.

So i need to be able to put a border on a togglebutton with a custom  design, that changes when activated/deactivated, keeping the border in both states. i have also tried setting the max width and max height, and also setting the padding on the buttons in an attempt to seperate them.

an example of the code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    ToggleButton tg1;
    ....
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ....
        tg1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        tg1.setOnClickListener(this);
        ....
        tg1.setBackgroundColor(0xffcccccc); //set button grey
    }
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if((tg1.isChecked()))
        {

            tg1.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ffff);   //set button blue
        }
        else
        {

            tg1.setBackgroundColor(0xffcccccc); //set button grey
        }
    }
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why dont you create a 9patch image with a border?

Comment: i tried using 9 patch images before but they would not work for me. also at the minute, i am using colours, not images, and would rather keep it that way if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Right way: do not call isChecked manually to change background. Use selector. You can draw 9-patch with a border or create [shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) (use stroke to set border color and solid to set fill color).

Or create a custom togglebutton to support desired functionality.